# joomla videobox plugin for local video

Tags: php, joomla2.5

I use plugin videobox for `joomla 2.5`. I working for video in youtube, vimeo,... but not working for video in local. My article:

```
{videobox}images/videos/stronger.mp4{/videobox}
```

i checked it with full url.
when i copy and paste full url in address bar of browser. it work
please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you have a relative vs absolute URL issue here. In the documentation for the plugin they are using the entire URL for the video. Try using that and see if it works. If you don't want to use the entire URL, try adding a `/` like this `{videobox}/images/videos/stronger.mp4{/videobox}`

Comment: Thank for help. I ready use full url in article and it not working.  url of my video: c:\appserv\www\mySite\images\videos\stronger.mp4

Comment: That's not a URL so it probably won't work with the plugin. Try http://localhost/mySite/images/videos/stronger.mp4.